# how to alter notification email in search api saved search module. I want to add more details about the search

Tags: search

I m using search api saved search module to save my search selected using facets.
In the notification email i want to add selected search options which i saved, Ex: country or city name which i selected while saving the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hook_mail_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) is your best friend, just keep in mind this hook fired on all emails so make sure you check if your are targeting the search-API emails. Here is a snippet of code copied from the [mail_example modul](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/email_example%21email_example.module/function/email_example_mail_alter/7)e:

```
function email_example_mail_alter(&$message) {
  // For the purpose of this example, modify all the outgoing messages and
  // attach a site signature. The signature will be translated to the language
  // in which message was built.
  $options = array(
    'langcode' => $message['language']->language,
  );

  $signature = t("\n--\nMail altered by email_example module.", array(), $options);
  if (is_array($message['body'])) {
    $message['body'][] = $signature;
  }
  else {
    // Some modules use the body as a string, erroneously.
    $message['body'] .= $signature;
  }
}
```